# Inner rollback transaction rolls back the outer too

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

I faced a problem like this. I have this transaction, and $(FilePath) specifies another script, that this should start running.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
:r $(FilePath)
GO
IF(@@ERROR <> 0)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END
```

(Note that the scripts that are called by the sqlcmd mostly doesn't contain transacions)
The problem is that, if the script that is being called contains a rollback transaction then it rolls back the outer transaction too. The inner scripts doesn't contain named transactions, and there are way too many scripts to rewrite each transaction to be named.

Is there a way to make this transaction only roll back if the corresponding rollback transaction runs?

Thank you

Comment: Name yours transactions like @NickyvV wrote.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have any control over the content of the scripts you're running - if that's the case, there's nothing you can do. SQL Server doesn't support genuine nested transactions.

Comment: Yes that is the case, I'm not allowed the rewrite the scripts, but I have to run them in transaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a `savepoint_name` with your `ROLLBACK` statement like described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx):
Without this savepoint the ROLLBACK statement rolls back transactions to the outermost `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement as designed.

```
ROLLBACK { TRAN | TRANSACTION } 
     [ transaction_name | @tran_name_variable
     | savepoint_name | @savepoint_variable ] 
[ ; ]
```

> ROLLBACK TRANSACTION without a savepoint_name or transaction_name
>   rolls back to the beginning of the transaction. When nesting
>   transactions, this same statement rolls back all inner transactions to
>   the outermost BEGIN TRANSACTION statement. In both cases, ROLLBACK
>   TRANSACTION decrements the @@TRANCOUNT system function to 0. ROLLBACK
>   TRANSACTION savepoint_name does not decrement @@TRANCOUNT.

Comment: Thank you, but that won't work. The problem is that there are already written transactions in the scripts, that have non-named transactions, and I'm not allowed to name them. Even if I would, this is still not an option because there are about 8-900 scripts.